# wxpython gauge does not pulsing

Tags: python, wxpython

I am struggling to get a gauge bar to pulse while a subprocess runs so I have gone back to basics and got this basic code which still does not work

```
import wx

class GaugeFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Gauge Example', size=(350, 150))
    panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
    self.gauge = wx.Gauge(panel, -1, 50, (20, 50), (250, 25))
    self.gauge.Pulse()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
GaugeFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I have tried the wxpython examples which shows two gauges one uses a wx.Timer and the other is set to pulse. When I remove the timer the gauge which is set to pulse stops working.

Therefore, i can only think that a gauge even set to pulse needs to have a timer.

is this correct?

I have tried adding

```
self.gauge.Refresh()
```

and

```
self.gauge.Refresh(True)
```

but neither seems to help

Anyone know of a solution

thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [Gauge document](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Gauge.html), You are required to call it periodically after making some progress. You have to call it again and again to show progress, Pulse is used for indeterminate mode but you can move a bit to indicate the user that some progress has been made.

But if you just want to fool around the progress then yes you should bind it to timer. Just calling it in init doesn't make any sense.

I have modified example demo code just to fool around, you can bind it to your sub-process and set some checkpoints and increase/decrease the gauge speed if you really want to run it in indeterminate mode.

```
import wx

class GaugeFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Gauge Example', size=(350, 150))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.fool = 0
        self.gspeed = 200
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(panel, -1, 50, (20, 50), (250, 25))
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(self.gspeed)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.TimerHandler)

    def __del__(self):
        self.timer.Stop()

    def TimerHandler(self, event):
        self.fool = self.fool+1
        if self.fool == 20:
            self.fool = 0
            self.gspeed = self.gspeed - 20
            if self.gspeed <= 0:
                self.timer.Stop()
                self.ShowMessage()
                self.Close()
            else:
                self.timer.Start(self.gspeed)
        self.gauge.Pulse()

    def ShowMessage(self):
        wx.MessageBox('Loading Completed', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
GaugeFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: so there is no way for it to just pulse away on launching until i set self.gauage.SetValue(100) which would show the user it has completed?

Comment: Yes , even I am also new to wxpython.. but that's what I understood from the docs out there.